# Monthly free GeoIP List from MaxMind adds/remove IPs every month. Can I trust older IPs?

Tags: ip-address, geoip, maxmind

I'm using Maxmind's free GeoIP List (Country Only). Every month they release updates for it. In new list they adds/removes IPs and assign previous month country IP to different country.

I have a SQL table stored with Users IP Address. (1 year data). Can I now compare those IP addresses with up-to-date maxmind database to find for specific country? Can I get 99.9% accuracy?

Any clarification would be helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.
Ganesh

Comment: I doubt there is an objective benchmark of this list. Even if there is, how do you know the benchmark is still valid? I'm afraid this question will only gather opinions, not objective answers.

Answer (score 1):

IPv4 addresses are in high demand due to scarcity. Companies are auctioning off subnets. For example, Microsoft is trying to buy up all the IPv4 addresses they can to keep up with Azure expansion. I think definitely you can't depend on old IPv4 geo information.